# Can't get a configuration file(google-services.json)

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase

I have tried so many times to access https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

but I can't.
when I access the site, I just see circle progress thing, and it never disappears.

Is there a problem in google or my account has the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: try this link:  https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=gcm&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cntpkg=gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messagin%2Fandroid%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Try%20Cloud%20Messaging

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet I tried it, but doesn't work....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My app is already in Play Store using older version of Google analytics and I have the similar problem with the endless spinning circle when I try to update my app and download the file google-services.json....

I double check my analytic property and the Google Play Console etc, try it on different platforms, browsers...

And then I realize that the document said "Google Developer Console".
I login in https://console.developers.google.com

and create a project for my app after I done that I am able to get the google-services.json from

https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

Comment: Oh my god! It works. Why there's no such direction in guide? Thank you so much!!

Comment: The Get Configuration link within the Google docs caused me the same problem, even though my app was already setup. Using the link above works.